# sql query multiple fields from a single form input

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql

I'm using php/mysql and jquery ui to auto-populate. What I need help with is querying two fields from the db (city, state) from a single input (chicago, il). What is throwing me is how to combine the fields in the query.

**Example that works**

```
SELECT City, State, MIN(Zip) AS Min_ZIP, MAX(Zip) AS Max_ZIP
FROM Zips
WHERE City = $foo // 'chicago'
OR Zip = $foo // '01234'
GROUP BY City, State
ORDER BY State;
```

**What I'd like to do, but not working**

```
SELECT City, State, MIN(Zip) AS Min_ZIP, MAX(Zip) AS Max_ZIP
FROM Zips
WHERE City = $foo // 'chicago'
OR
City+', '+State = $foo // 'chicago, il'
OR Zip = $foo // '01234'
GROUP BY City, State
ORDER BY State;
```

(BTW - The state field is an abbreviation.)

The reasoning is that some city names are only 3 or 4 letters and are contained within other city names so the user may need to type a comma and the state to see the auto-suggestion pop-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried **CONCAT_WS** on my db and it worked out fine, the following query should work for you.

Syntax for CONCAT_WS is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws): first argument is the separator used to concatenate the strings, which are the other arguments

```
SELECT City, State, MIN(Zip) AS Min_ZIP, MAX(Zip) AS Max_ZIP
FROM Zips
WHERE City = $foo // 'chicago'
OR
CONCAT_WS(', ',City, State) = $foo // 'chicago, il'
OR Zip = $foo // '01234'
GROUP BY City, State
ORDER BY State;
```

Comment: Keep in mind that performing a function on the fields will slow down the query as the function will have to be performed on every row in the table. I think a better answer would be to split $foo by ',' and then trim the whitespace. The first term is now the City and the second term, if any, is the state.

Comment: @Evil I'll keep that in mind and use php split if I need to break them up. list($city, $state) = split(', ', $_GET['term']);

Answer (score 0):

Split your input string before running your query so that you can do:

```
SELECT City, State, MIN(Zip) AS Min_ZIP, MAX(Zip) AS Max_ZIP
FROM Zips
WHERE City = 'chicago'
OR Zip = '01234'
GROUP BY City, State
ORDER BY State;
```

The state becomes irrelevant if they've also specified chicago.

Comment: the city state and zip are the same variable field being passed in

Comment: they are coming in on keystrokes not all at once. so 'chica' would bring up multiple cities, which is fine, then as the user types more 'chicago' it would auto-suggest the different cities in different states named 'chicago' (yes there are some), then as the user defines even more 'chicago, i' it will only auto-suggest chicago, il

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
SELECT City, State, MIN(Zip) AS Min_ZIP, MAX(Zip) AS Max_ZIP
FROM Zips
WHERE City = 'chicago'
OR( City LIKE "chicago,%" AND State LIKE '%illinois')

OR Zip = '01234'
GROUP BY City, State
ORDER BY State;
```

Comment: but i can't separate chicago and illinois. they come in together, combined in the same field (i.e. chicago, illinois)

Comment: Well, i think this is not the best way for going on. if you want not to do your search for state names shorter than 4 char you can actually give up giving autocompletion (actually, if it's 3-4 char, the user should not be helped by autocomplete that it's usefull with long words).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest wrapping your string concatenation in parenthesis.  You could also use a function like CONCAT() or CONCAT_WS() in MySQL.

And what do you mean by "it doesn't work" ?  The clause breaks or ... ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT City, State, MIN(Zip) AS Min_ZIP, MAX(Zip) AS Max_ZIP
FROM
   (SELECT City, State, Zip, (City +', ' + State) AS CityState
    FROM Zips) as SQ
WHERE City = $foo // 'chicago'
OR
CityState = $foo // 'chicago, il'
OR Zip = $foo // '01234'
GROUP BY City, State
ORDER BY State;
```